# How to open 25 files with same structure and copy content in one file on c shell with cdo commands

Tags: linux, shell, csh, cdo-climate

I have 25 files with the same structure with 19 columns.

I want to open every file and copy from 3 to 19 column in other file using c shell.

The files is named like that:

```
2005090600
2005090603 
2005090606
2005090609
2005090612
2005090615
2005090618
2005090621
2005090624
2005090627
2005090630
2005090633
2005090636
2005090639
2005090642
2005090645
2005090648
2005090651
2005090654
2005090657
2005090660
2005090663
2005090666
2005090669
2005090672
```

The structure of every file look like this, but every file have 19 columns:

```
  23.78060      40.71370     288.82779       1.48891      78.58701    1021.$
  23.83990      40.71460     289.06360       1.67858      71.84100    1018.$
  23.89920      40.71550     289.40170       2.15609      67.67834    1020.$
  23.95850      40.71630     289.53516       2.74299      66.69261    1020.$
  24.01770      40.71720     289.19260       3.15175      70.89188    1017.$
  24.07700      40.71790     288.84558       3.48898      75.21935    1015.$
  24.13630      40.71870     288.67654       3.72929      77.41970    1018.$
  24.19560      40.71940     288.68100       3.91989      78.33372    1020.$
  24.25490      40.72010     288.74329       3.97584      77.75845    1020.$
  24.31410      40.72070     288.81891       3.83177      76.72694    1019.$
  24.37340      40.72130     288.86340       3.47986      75.53368    1018.$
  24.43270      40.72190     288.97015       2.86700      74.33279    1019.$
  24.49200      40.72250     289.07248       2.12211      73.56832    1020.$
  24.55130      40.72300     288.53864       1.39689      72.50629    1008.$
  24.61060      40.72350     287.37305       0.82412      75.36126     984.$
  24.66990      40.72390     287.01270       0.45068      78.88762     978.$
  24.72920      40.72430     288.14270       0.25516      81.30769     999.$
  24.78850      40.72470     288.97461       0.52074      79.94659    1019.$
  24.84770      40.72510     289.08139       1.04584      78.00870    1020.$
```

I want to open every file and paste content from 3 to 19 columns in another new file named grid_aladin.txt in the same directory.

Can I get example how to loop with cdo command on c shell every file and copy content in the file grid_aladin.txt

grid_aladin.txt look like this:

```
gridtype = latlon
xsize = 10612
ysize = 10612
xvals = 23.7806 23.8399 23.8992 23.9585 24.0177 24.077 24.1363 24.1956 24.2549 24.3141 24.3734 24.4327 24.492 24.5513 24.6106 24.6699 24.7292 24.7885 24.8477 24.907 24.9663 25.0256 25.0849 25.1442 25.2035 25.2628 25.3221 25.3814 25.4407$
yvals = 40.7137 40.7146 40.7155 40.7163 40.7172 40.7179 40.7187 40.7194 40.7201 40.7207 40.7213 40.7219 40.7225 40.723 40.7235 40.7239 40.7243 40.7247 40.7251 40.7254 40.7257 40.726 40.7262 40.7264 40.7266 40.7268 40.7269 40.727 40.727 $
```

My code on C shell:

```
# cdo: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file
#gawk '{ print $3 }' 2005090672 | cdo -f nc input,grid_aladin.txt 2005090672_AT_.nc
#cdo chname,var1,air_temp 2005090672_AT_.nc 2005090672_AT.nc
#cdo -setattribute,air_temp@units="degC" -addc,-273.15 2005090672_AT.nc 2005090672_AT_.nc
#cdo -shifttime,72hour -settunits,hours -settaxis,2020-05-09,06:00,1hour 2005090672_AT_.nc 2005090672_AT.nc


#SET Dat_A="20050906"
#SET Yea_A="2020"
#SET Month_A="05"
#SET Day_A="09"
# files-25
hour_file=['00','03','06','09','12','15','18','21','24','27','30','33','36','39','42','45','48','51','54','57','60','63','6$
hour_number=[0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72]
# vars-10
var_name=['air_temp','w_speed','rel_hum','surf_ps','nebu','rain1','rain2','snow1','snow2','rglo']
var_fname=['AT','WS','RH','PS','NB','RR1','RR2','SN1','SN2','GR']
var_unit=['degC','m/s','%','Pas','0-1','mm','mm','mm','mm','W']
var_position=[3,4,5,6,14,15,16,17,18,19]

#loop on variables

#loop on files

gawk '{ print $${var_position} }' ${Dat_A}${hour_file} | cdo -f nc input,grid_aladin.txt ${Dat_A}${hour_file}_${var_fname}_$
cdo -setattribute,${var_name}@units="${var_unit}" -chname,var1,$var_name -shifttime,${hour_number}hour -settunits,hours \
    -settaxis,${Year_A}-${Month_A}-${Day_A},06:00,1hour ${Dat_A}${hour_file}_${var_fname}_.nc ${Dat_A}${hour_file}_${var_fn$
rm ${Dat_A}${hour_file}_${var_fname}_.nc

#end loop files

cdo -mergetime ${Dat_A}*_${var_fname}.nc ${Dat_A}_${var_fname}.nc

#end loop variables

cdo merge ${Dat_A}_*.nc ${Dat_A}.nc

#remap file
```

Can I get example how to loop this files and save the content in the grid_aladin.txt ?

Comment: why not just `awk '{print $3, $4, $5, .... $19}' *wildCardFileSpec* > aggregateFile.txt` (You may have to mess around with `awk -F\t` and/or `-v OFS="|"` or similar to get the fields working the way you want. See [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) for further details. Good luck.

Comment: I just want to put the files in array an use while or do while to get all content and put to another file

Comment: Can I take some example with your comment ?

Comment: Sorry, there is too much here to comprehend. I see at least 2 questions (*"open every file and paste content from 3 to 19 column..."* , and *"Can I get example how to loop with cdo command "*). Please simplify your problem by eliminating any use of variables that are strictly needed for your prolblem. I have given you a starter for `1:` and it looks like you have something for  `2:` . `.....`

Comment: To simplify your Q you can reduce the size of the problem description. If a solutions will work for 2-3 variables and columns and lines of data, it will be easy to expand it to work for your full problem. Good luck.